# How to use sphero unity plugin?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sphero-api

I'm trying to use sphero  unity plugin.
I'm download from GitHub. Evrything is OK but when I'm trying to lauch the sample app from Ipad2 it crashe.
I'm also try with the unity plugin in the asset store.
Did I forget anything ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We are seeing this crash on some projects because the "-all_load" linker flag isn't added in the xcodeproject.  See this other stackoverflow project for a more detailed solution.

[Sphero iOS Unity Plugin - Crash Following Sphero Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341321/sphero-ios-unity-plugin-crash-following-sphero-connect)